# url rewrite htaccess in hindi text GET URl value

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have multiple url like domainname/भारतीय_अर्थव्यवस्था Here I am want to get only भारतीय_अर्थव्यवस्था for database Comparison for get data in this category

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Give the htaccess file to see what rules are in place.

Comment: Please rephrase your question and add some code to see what you tried so far

Comment: Have you tried looking at `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`?

Comment: Yes like echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .htaccess file you should have some simple "nice URL" rule, for example (modify for your own needs):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* db.php
```

Then you can get the string in PHP code:

```
<?php
    header ("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

    // Get only the path component
    $data = parse_url ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

    // Get only the last part
    $data = basename ($data);

    // Handle plus sign correctly when using urldecode on the path component
    $data = str_replace ("+", "%2B", $data);

    // Decode
    $data = urldecode ($data);

    print $data;
?>
```